# Mac installer that runs a script

Tags: macos, installation, scripting

I need to create an installer for a Mac application that not only unpacks the information but executes an script before unpacking the information. Also I want an interactive application that asks for some parameters during installation.

Do you know any tool to do that staff?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`/Developer/Applications/Utilities/PackageMaker.app`

will let you make `.pkg` installer bundles, these can include pre and post scripts along with files.

If you can't ask for the information you need during the install, consider moving it to the application when it does a first run.